# Magento 1.9 create log for no-route

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, log

Is there anyway I can force Magento to create a log file that contains the offending script path that is causing a redirect to no-route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create small module

config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <routeurfrontend>
            <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Module_Noroughtlog</module>
                    <frontName>error</frontName>
                </args>
        </routeurfrontend>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Add below code on IndexController.php

```
class Module_Noroughtlog_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        Mage::log($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri()), null, "404-url-list.log");
    }
}
```